# measuring WLAN using python for S60

Tags: python, pys60, wifi

I'm using python for S60. is there a module that enable you to measure WLAN intensity in your area? 
In the end I want to get a list with all the networks available in the point and their intensity.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is: http://chris.berger.cx/PyS60/PyS60